# Searching words with ANY repeating characters

Tags: regex, perl

Looking for a perl one-liner what will find all words with the next pattern:

```
X(not_X_chrs)X(not_X_chrs)X    e.g. cyclic
```

For one character, it is easy, e.g. for 'a'

```
perl -nle 'print if /^a[^a]+a[^a]+a$/' < /usr/share/dict/web2
```

but I want search for **ANY** character, so, looking for one regex for finding **all** words like:

```
azalea   #repeating a
baobab   #repeating b
cyclic   #c
```

and so on..

tried this:

```
perl -nle 'print if m/^([a-z])[^$1]+$1[^$1]+$1$/i' </usr/share/dict/web2
```

but not works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(?:(?!STRING).)
```

is to

```
(?:STRING)
```

as

```
[^CHAR]
```

is to

```
CHAR
```

so you could use

```
/
   ^
   (\pL)
   (?:
      (?:(?!\1).)+
      \1
   ){2}
   \z
/sx
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the best regex I could come up with:

```
^([a-z])((?:(?!\1).)+\1){2}$
```

Tested on [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a lazy quantifier with an atomic non-backtracking group:

```
^(\w)(?>\w*?\1){2}$
```

Altho that only works when 0 intermediate characters is acceptable.

With at least 1 character you'd have to use a negative lookahead:

```
^(\w)(?>(?!\1)\w+?\1){2}$
```

Answer (score 0):

In [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Backreferences) it says that you can backreference in a regex (not the right part of a substitution) using `\g1`. This was changed in 5.14. Since I only have 5.12.2 here I have to use `\1` instead.

Therefore, your original regex with a tiny adjustion worked for me:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use 5.12.2;
use feature qw(say);
for (qw/ azalea baobab cyclic deadend teeeeeestest doesnotwork /) {
  say if m/^([a-z])[^\1]+\1[^\1]+\1$/i;
}
```

Looking at it with [YAPE::Regex::Explain](http://search.cpan.org/~gsullivan/YAPE-Regex-Explain-4.01/Explain.pm)

```
use YAPE::Regex::Explain;
print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new(qr/^([a-z])[^\1]+\1[^\1]+\1$/i)->explain();
```

yields:

```
The regular expression:

(?i-msx:^([a-z])[^\1]+\1[^\1]+\1$)

matches as follows:


use YAPE::Regex::Explain;
print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new(qr/^([a-z])[^\1]+\1[^\1]+\1$/i)->explain();

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?i-msx:                 group, but do not capture (case-insensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\1]+                   any character except: '\1' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \1                       what was matched by capture \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\1]+                   any character except: '\1' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \1                       what was matched by capture \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Edit**: Your one-liner therefore is `perl -e 'print if m/^([a-z])[^\1]+\1[^\1]+\1$/i'`.

On another note, if you had tried `perl -w -e 'print if m/(as)$1/'` you'd have seen your problem immediately:

```
$ perl -w -e 'print if m/(a)$1/' asdf
Use of uninitialized value $1 in regexp compilation at -e line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at -e line 1.
```

---

What I have not figured out is why it matches `ololololo`.